# raspberry pi zero w process load handling

Tags: process

this is my first project with Raspberry pi.
i want to make a Testing chamber for growing micro greens(small plants).

What this chamber does is following:

1- weigh the the 4 growing pods with load-cell and HX711 (four of each of them)

2- control Humidity and temperature with DHT22 attached to relay board to turn on or off the heater and humidifier (one DHT22) and also turn off and on the exhaust fan.

3- Control light hours (turn on and of in specific time) with relay

4- control growing medium moisture with capacitive moisture sensor (CSMO v1.2) - sensor controls the solenoid valves to water the pods with relay board whenever medium is got dry. since out pot signal is analog i use MCP3008 to convert it to digital

5- each pod has flow meter attached to its watering pipes to measure how much water is used.

to be short i have the following sensors that i want to control with RPI zero W:

4* Load cells (YZC-133) with 4 HX711 for each one
4* Solenoid valves.
4* Capacitive moisture sensors (CSMO v1.2) with 1 MCP3008
4* Flow meters
1* Humidifier
1* DHT22
1* Exhaust Fan
1* Heater
1* Light
2* 4 Channel relay board
(schematic wiring is attached )

**So here are my questions:

1 - could R PI zero W handle the processing load of controlling these sensors?**

**2- is it possible to do this project with ESP32? could ESP32 handle these sensor's processing load?**

i appreciate any suggestion for doing this project.

schematic wiring:
http://uupload.ir/files/ke1t_schematic_wiring.jpg

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: upvote for the nicely drawn wiring diagram ..... overlooking the two upside down grounds

Comment: just curious .... why do you need to weigh the growing pods?

Comment: if you wonder how much workload it would be for a microcontroller ..... it would be like showing up at work for 5 minutes once a month

Comment: @jsotola, i want to track how much weight each kind of seed gains in time to decide when is more profitable for me to harvest them,

Comment: do the load cells have the resolution necessary for measuring the weight gain?

Comment: i want to use YZC-133 LoadCell 5kg, these sensor will measure weight 1 time in 24 hours. one of my friend suggested me to use this loadcell. do you think it'll work or i have to change it?

Comment: by the way, these are how pods look like:http://s9.picofile.com/file/8351761050/Growing_Pod_02.jpg    http://s8.picofile.com/file/8351761018/Growing_Pod_01.jpg        http://s9.picofile.com/file/8351945284/004_P_002.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1. could R PI zero W handle the processing load of controlling these sensors?

Yes.

> 2. could ESP32 handle these sensor's processing load?

While not related to Raspberry Pi, it can handle the load.

You're talking about growing plants. So there is no need to query the sensors thousands of times per second.

Define the reaction times you need for each events, then estimate how long it takes to process them.